# Property object is not callable

Tags: object, properties

Let's say I have a code like this

```
@property
def Inverted_string(str):
    return str[::-1]

print(Inverted_string("123"))
```

When I print out `Inverted_string("123")`, it gives me an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Python Project\Test.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(Inverted_string("123"))
TypeError: 'property' object is not callable
```

How can I access to the returned value of `Inverted_string()` as a string **without remove the `@property` decorator** above this function? I tried `str(Inverted_string("123"))` but it doesn't work since the function itself is not callable, according to the error.

NOTE: This just a test function, my real code is far more complicate than this, but I can't just copy and paste them up here since read them would take eternity :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
@property
def Inverted_string(str):
    return str[::-1]

print((Inverted_string.__get__('123')))
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?